# cannot implicitly convert type int to int'

Tags: c#, class, dictionary, type-conversion

```
class TransactionManager
{
   // private Dictionary<int, Transaction> transactions = new Dictionary<int, Transaction>();
    private Dictionary<int, Item> Transactions = new Dictionary<int, Item>();

    public void NewTransaction(Item i)
    {
        Transactions.Add(i.code, i);
    }

    public Dictionary<int, Transaction> FindTransaction()
    {
        return Transactions;
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems like just a typo.  It looks like you meant to make the return value for `FindTransaction` to be `Dictionary<int, Item>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your have `Dictionary<int, Item>`, then your return type of method should have the same type:

```
public Dictionary<int, Item> FindTransaction()
{
    return Transactions;
}
```